# Why won't the following code retrieve the specified Registry key value

Tags: c#, registry

Environment Win 10 v20H2 in HP Spectre

I have an Excel Addin which creates the following registry entry

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\VB and VBA Program Settings\Fisk\Installation\Environment
```

I am writing a C# program to retrieve the value of that key, but it keeps returning a null value.

What is wrong with the following code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace Fisk_Environment
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\VB and VBA Program Settings\Fisk\Installation\Environment");

            if (key != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show((string)key.GetValue("Settings"));
                key.Close();
            }

            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node\VB....` though registry redirection should happen automatically. Worth a shot

Comment: Same result unfortunately

Comment: Try writing to a key in the same folder and then verify it's in the registry. Something tells me your path is wrong

Comment: Making the following changes  
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\VB and VBA Program Settings\Fisk\Installation");   and
MessageBox.Show((string)key.GetValue("Environment"));
has corrected my problem. My understanding of subkeys was lacking. Thanks very much for your assistance